# Equation of ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the equation of the locus of a point which moves so that the sum of its distances from the point (2,1) and (8,1) is 10.

I have tried so many times, but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic approach.** What is the center $C$ of the ellipse?  It is the midpoint of the line segment connecting the two foci.  You should also note that the major axis is coincident with this line segment.  (Why?)

What is (the length of) the major axis?  It's the constant sum of the distances of the locus from the two foci.  (Why?)

What is the minor axis?  The minor axis, the distance between the two foci, and the major axis constitute a Pythagorean triple.  (Why?)

With these three facts, you should be able to determine the equation of the ellipse in the form

$$
\frac{(x-x_C)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_C)^2}{b^2} = 1
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are the *semi*-major and *semi*-minor axis, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;\;$ Denoting the point by $(x,y)$, start with

$\hspace{.5 in}\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-8)^2+(y-1)^2}=10$.

This gives $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}=10-\sqrt{(x-8)^2+(y-1)^2}$, and squaring both sides yields

$(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=100-20\sqrt{(x-8)^2+(y-1)^2}+(x-8)^2+(y-1)^2$,

so $\;20\sqrt{(x-8)^2+(y-1)^2}=160-12x$ and $5\sqrt{(x-8)^2+(y-1)^2}=40-3x$.

Now continue by squaring both sides and simplifying; you should obtain the equation of an ellipse.